# Show that the point $P(x,y,z)$ is equidistant from the two points $A(3,-2,1)$ and $B(1,2,4)$ if and only if $4x-8y-6z+7=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's the full question:

> Show that the point $P(x,y,z)$ is equidistant from the two points
> $A(3,-2,1)$ and $B(1,2,4)$ if and only if $4x-8y-6z+7=0$. Where do the points $P$ whose coordinates satisfy this equation lie?

Before I get to my work on this so far, just a few assumptions. We are dealing with a rectangular and isometric coordinate system. Let $d(CD)$ denote the distance between any two points $C$, $D$.

Okay, so this is how far I got:

---

Suppose point $P(x,y,z)$ is equidistant from the two points $A(3,-2,1)$ and $B(1,2,4)$, i.e. $d(AP) = d(PB)$. Let's first find $d(AB)$ --> $$\begin{align} d(AB) &= \sqrt{(1-3)^2+(2+2)^2+(4-1)^2}  \\&=\sqrt{29} \end{align}$$
Then $d(AP) = d(PB) = \frac{d(AB)}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{29}}{2}$.

Furthermore,
$$\begin{align} [d(AP)]^2 = \frac{29}{4}  &= (x-3)^2+(y+2)^2+(z-1)^2 \\ &= x^2+y^2+z^2 -6x+4y-2z+14\end{align} $$ And, $$\begin{align} [d(PB)]^2 = \frac{29}{4}  &= (x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-4)^2 \\&= x^2+y^2+z^2-2x-4y-8z+21 \end{align}$$ Finally, $$[d(PB)]^2 -[d(AP)]^2 = 0 = 4x-8y-6z+7$$

---

Before I show that that the converse is true (which I have a hard time doing) I have an issue with my above solution. Specifically, I have an issue with this step --> $$d(AP) = d(PB) = \frac{d(AB)}{2}$$

I feel like I'm assuming that point $P$ is "between" points $A$ and $B$ such that $A, B, 
\text{and} \; P$ lie on the same line. For example, if $A, B, 
\text{and} \; P$ were vertices of an equilateral triangle, then it's true that $d(AP) = d(PB)$, but it's not true that $d(AP) = d(PB) = \frac{d(AB)}{2}$. Before I move on, can someone explain why I'm having this issue?

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter what I put for $d(AP)=d(PB)$ since they will subtract to $0$ anyway, so should I just give it an arbitrary distance?

Comment: Nice question with many possible  methods to solve. Find a plane perpedicular to line AB. Or simply choose three random points from the plain and calculate distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach:

Since distances measured are always positive, you have that the distances are equal if and only if  the square of the distances are equal.

Therefore

$$(x - 3)^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z - 1)^2\tag1$$

equals

$$(x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z - 4)^2.\tag2$$

Multiplying out both of (1) and (2) above, and canceling out the $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$ terms from (1) and (2) above, you get

$$(-6x + 9) + (4y + 4) + (-2z + 1)\tag3$$

equals

$$(-2x + 1) + (-4y + 4) + (-8z + 6)\tag4.$$

Immediate that comparison of (3) and (4) above produces the desired result.  Minor point is that superficially, the implications are one-way.  That is, if (1) equals (2) then (3) equals (4).

However, closer inspection of the math used indicates that the implications are actually two-way.  That is, it is straightforward to show that if (3) equals (4), then (1) equals (2).

Comment: Got it! Because if $(3)$ equals $(4)$, then I can just add $x^2+y^2+z^2$ to both equations and get $(1)$ equals $(2)$. I think your solution makes the most sense in terms of the context of the chapter this problem showed up in, so I'm accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the distance between $P$ and $A$ is equal to the distance between $P$ and $B$ then

$(P- A)^T (P - A) = (P - B)^T (P - B)$

Expanding both the left and right hand sides,

$P^T P - 2 P^T A + A^T A = P^T P - 2 P^T B + B^T B $

From which,

$P^T (B - A) = \frac{1}{2} (B^T B - A^T A) $

Now $A = (3,-2,1), B = (1,2,4) $, therefore $(B - A) = (-2, 4, 3) $ and
$\frac{1}{2} (B^T B - A^T A) = \frac{1}{2} (21 - 14) = \dfrac{7}{2}$ hence

$ - 2 x + 4 y + 3 z = \dfrac{7}{2} $

which can be re-arranged into

$ 4 x - 8 y - 6 z + 7 = 0 $

Answer (score 0):

Since the mid-point $M(2,0,\frac{5}{2})$ of $AB$ satisfies the condition $MA=MB$, $$\therefore PA=PB $$
$$\Leftrightarrow 
\overrightarrow{A B} \perp \overrightarrow{P M}
$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  \textrm{ P lies on the plane passing M and with normal vector } \overrightarrow{AB} $$

$$\Leftrightarrow -2(x-2)+4(y-0)+3\left(z-\frac{5}{2}\right)=0 $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow 4 x-8-8 y-6 z+15=0 $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow 4 x-8 y-6 z+7=0 
$$